# How to patch --dry-run but still view rejects?

Tags: patch

I want to test a patch using `--dry-run`, but when it fails, I don't get any reject files. Is there any way to do a dry run but keep the reject files so I can see what went wrong?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a dry run *not* to cause any changes *at all*? How about just making a copy of everything and patching that?

Comment: I have the same problem. To me the point of a dry run would be to not only see *that* a patch fails, but also *where*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`patch -o /dev/null` (without `--dry-run`) should send the successful hunks into oblivion and keep the reject files.

Comment: This does not work. It gives following error `patch: **** File /dev/null is not a regular file -- can't patch`

Comment: for me (patch v2.5.4)  `-o /dev/null` causes patch to try to write reject to `/dev/null.rej` so I just need to add `--reject-file`, otherwise yes, it works.

Comment: Fails for me on patch 2.7.5: `patch: patch.c:1419: apply_hunk: Assertion \`outstate->after_newline' failed.`